# assign() converts data frames into strings?

Tags: r

I have code like this:

```
library(stringdist)
library(stringr)
for (j in seq(1,50))
{
  ide <-ide_in_tf3c[[j]] # id
  file1 <- paste("/something/can_seq_", ide, ".csv", sep="")
  impo1 <- read_delim(file1, "¿", escape_double = FALSE,
  col_names = FALSE, comment = "*>", trim_ws = TRUE)
  pdb<-impo1$X1
  nde<-stringr::str_replace(impo1$X2, '�', '')
  tde<-stringr::str_replace(impo1$X3, '�', '')
  sec0<-stringr::str_replace(impo1$X4, '�', '')
  sec<-stringr::str_replace_all(sec0, '\\\\n', '')
  oname1 = paste("df", "_", ide, sep="")
  assign(oname1, data.frame(pdb, nde, tde, sec)) # assign
  file2 <- paste("/something/cons_", ide, "_c", sep="")
  impo2 <- read_csv(file2, col_names = FALSE)
  oname2 = paste("cons_", ide, sep="")
  assign(oname2, impo2$X1) 
# n<-nrow(oname1)
#   for (i in seq(1,n))
#   {
#     y<-adist(oname1$sec[i], oname2)
#     print(y)
# }
}
```

The part commented out does not work, I am not sure why.
I am importing 50 files in `csv` format (with 4 columns and different rows) and assign those 50 files to 50 data frames (as far as I  understand). Then I do the same with a text file where I have a string. What I want to do is to compare this string to the fourth column of each file with `adist` from the `stringdist` library. The problem is that `n` get the value `NULL` probably because I am using `paste` to get the name of the files/objects?

This is the result of `head -n 5 can_seq_P0DTD1.csv`

```
5RE4¿1¿polypeptide(L)¿SGFRKMAFPSGKVEGCMVQVTCGTTTLNGLWLDDVVYCPRHVICTSEDMLNPNYEDLLIRKSNHNFLVQAGNVQLRVIGH\nSMQNCVLKLKVDTANPKTPKYKFVRIQPGQTFSVLACYNGSPSGVYQCAMRPNFTIKGSFLNGSCGSVGFNIDYDCVSFC\nYMHHMELPTGVHAGTDLEGNFYGPFVDRQTAQAAGTDTTITVNVLAWLYAAVINGDRWFLNRFTTTLNDFNLVAMKYNYE\nPLTQDHVDILGPLSAQTGIAVLDMCASLKELLQNGMNGRTILGSALLEDEFTPFDVVRQCSGVTFQ
5RE6¿1¿polypeptide(L)¿SGFRKMAFPSGKVEGCMVQVTCGTTTLNGLWLDDVVYCPRHVICTSEDMLNPNYEDLLIRKSNHNFLVQAGNVQLRVIGH\nSMQNCVLKLKVDTANPKTPKYKFVRIQPGQTFSVLACYNGSPSGVYQCAMRPNFTIKGSFLNGSCGSVGFNIDYDCVSFC\nYMHHMELPTGVHAGTDLEGNFYGPFVDRQTAQAAGTDTTITVNVLAWLYAAVINGDRWFLNRFTTTLNDFNLVAMKYNYE\nPLTQDHVDILGPLSAQTGIAVLDMCASLKELLQNGMNGRTILGSALLEDEFTPFDVVRQCSGVTFQ
5RE7¿1¿polypeptide(L)¿SGFRKMAFPSGKVEGCMVQVTCGTTTLNGLWLDDVVYCPRHVICTSEDMLNPNYEDLLIRKSNHNFLVQAGNVQLRVIGH\nSMQNCVLKLKVDTANPKTPKYKFVRIQPGQTFSVLACYNGSPSGVYQCAMRPNFTIKGSFLNGSCGSVGFNIDYDCVSFC\nYMHHMELPTGVHAGTDLEGNFYGPFVDRQTAQAAGTDTTITVNVLAWLYAAVINGDRWFLNRFTTTLNDFNLVAMKYNYE\nPLTQDHVDILGPLSAQTGIAVLDMCASLKELLQNGMNGRTILGSALLEDEFTPFDVVRQCSGVTFQ
5RE8¿1¿polypeptide(L)¿SGFRKMAFPSGKVEGCMVQVTCGTTTLNGLWLDDVVYCPRHVICTSEDMLNPNYEDLLIRKSNHNFLVQAGNVQLRVIGH\nSMQNCVLKLKVDTANPKTPKYKFVRIQPGQTFSVLACYNGSPSGVYQCAMRPNFTIKGSFLNGSCGSVGFNIDYDCVSFC\nYMHHMELPTGVHAGTDLEGNFYGPFVDRQTAQAAGTDTTITVNVLAWLYAAVINGDRWFLNRFTTTLNDFNLVAMKYNYE\nPLTQDHVDILGPLSAQTGIAVLDMCASLKELLQNGMNGRTILGSALLEDEFTPFDVVRQCSGVTFQ
5RE9¿1¿polypeptide(L)¿SGFRKMAFPSGKVEGCMVQVTCGTTTLNGLWLDDVVYCPRHVICTSEDMLNPNYEDLLIRKSNHNFLVQAGNVQLRVIGH\nSMQNCVLKLKVDTANPKTPKYKFVRIQPGQTFSVLACYNGSPSGVYQCAMRPNFTIKGSFLNGSCGSVGFNIDYDCVSFC\nYMHHMELPTGVHAGTDLEGNFYGPFVDRQTAQAAGTDTTITVNVLAWLYAAVINGDRWFLNRFTTTLNDFNLVAMKYNYE\nPLTQDHVDILGPLSAQTGIAVLDMCASLKELLQNGMNGRTILGSALLEDEFTPFDVVRQCSGVTFQ
```

This is the result of `cat cons_P0DTD1_c`

```
SGFRKMAFPSGKVEGCMVQVTCGTTTLNGLWLDDVVYCPRHVICTSEDMLNPNYEDLLIRKSNHNFLVQAGNVQLRVIGHSMQNCVLKLKVDTANPKTPKYKFVRIQPGQTFSVLACYNGSPSGVYQCAMRPNFTIKGSFLNGSCGSVGFNIDYDCVSFCYMHHMELPTGVHAGTDLEGNFYGPFVDRQTAQAAGTDTTITVNVLAWLYAAVINGDRWFLNRFTTTLNDFNLVAMKYNYEPLTQDHVDILGPLSAQTGIAVLDMCASLKELLQNGMNGRTILGSALLEDEFTPFDVVRQCSGVTFQ
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we extract a single column with `$` or `[[`, or with `[` after a `,` on a `data.frame`, it would be a `vector`.  Instead, we can subset the with `[`

```
assign(oname2, impo2['X1'])
```

In the commented line

```
n <- nrow(oname1)
```

'oname1' object have a string value.  To get the value of that string, use

```
nrow(get(oname1)) # nrow works only if the dataset assigned is data.frame
```

and in the loop

```
for(i in seq(1, n)) {
   y <- adist(get(oname1)$sec[i], get(oname2))
   print(y)
    }
```

---

The structure can be checked

```
str(mtcars['mpg'])
#'data.frame':  32 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...

str(mtcars$mpg)
#num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
```